# Is it possible to set bounce height on CSS text animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am pretty new to css and doing some animations for a friends website. Although I seem to have ran into an issue.

The following animation is a bouncing effect on a text field:

```
.text {
    animation: text-pop-up-top 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) infinite alternate both;
}

@keyframes text-pop-up-top {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #cccccc, 0 2px 0 #cccccc, 0 3px 0 #cccccc, 0 4px 0 #cccccc, 0 5px 0 #cccccc, 0 6px 0 #cccccc, 0 7px 0 #cccccc, 0 8px 0 #cccccc, 0 9px 0 #cccccc, 0 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}
```

But the text bounces way too high and is overlapping other text. Is it possible to set the height so it only goes up half the height as set? I apologize if this is an easy solution I haven't been able to figure it out. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line you want to adjust is this one:

```css
transform: translateY(-50px);
```

Try adjusting it to:

```css
transform: translateY(-25px);
```

**Update**

You may also want to adjust the last part of `text-shadow`, to decrease the vertical distance of the shadow to remain consistent with the lowered `translateY` value.

Change this:

```css
text-shadow: … 0 50px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
              /* ^^ */
```

To this:

```css
text-shadow: … 0 25px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
              /* ^^ */
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm5zgy02/)

Comment: Perfect thank you, I can't believe I missed this. I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @JasonWaltz. I made another update to decrease the `y` distance of the `text-shadow`. Have a look at the update.

Comment: Very useful information, I have been playing around with these settings and it looks much better now. Thanks Andy